# Sharepoint 2007 - Missing sites after after content database attachment

Tags: sharepoint-2007

I have a new SharePoint server which I've attached a content database to. The new server is configured like the old one (same  deployed solutions, settings, etc) and there was no errors when we attached the content database (which is a copy of the old server's content database).

At first, it looked fine, the site on the new server was working. But then we discovered that som sites couldn't be reached, when we try, we'll get a "404 File not found" error. The strange thing is that we can clearly see the sites in Manage Content Structure but when we try to open them, we get errors.

[image: Screen shot]

The error only occurs for a site called "Webbplatser" and all of it's subsites. The other sites, like Sök is working just fine. I can browse all the sites under "Webbplatser" without any problem from "Manage Content and Structure". I can see the default.aspx page for all the sites but when I try to open any of them, I'll get the 404 File not found error.

Anyone recognise this error? We are using Sharepoint 2007. Please help.

Comment: Are you able to open these sites in SharePoint Designer?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like there could be some site solution missing, perhaps even custom master pages or page layouts that were added in the 12 hive on which the Webbplatser site is reliant.

Use the the url of the webbplatser site and tack on the _layouts/settings.aspx to see if you can get to the site settings and see what is set up there. Failing that I'd do a directory tree compare between your old server and the new one, focusing on the 12 hive.